# Hibernate Criteria sort 2 params Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql

I'm stucking on Hibernate when create query to sort by 2 params in 1 table.

My table is:

```
Name (Integer) | Index (Integer) | ClassId (Integer) | Enable (Boolean)
```

I want to create SQL to sort data after get from DB by 2 fields: Enable and Index. I think it will same with:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY Enable DESC AND Index ASC.
```

But seem Hibernate Criteria only support to sort 1 params. Because I already add it 2 fields to criteria but the result only sort for Index.

Please give me advice about it ;)

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can order the results using org.hibernate.criterion.Order. 
Check the example below.

```
List cats = session.createCriteria(TABLE.class)
    .addOrder( Order.desc("Enable"))
    .addOrder( Order.asc("Index"))
    .setMaxResults(50)
    .list();
```